# internet problem

Tags: windows-xp, internet

On my laptop i have a weird problem, none of my web browsers can access the internet.
But msn messenger and Thunderbird are perfectly working. I have a wireless broadband connection. My guess is some viruses may block my port:80.

Comment: "all the things to solve this problem" like what?

Comment: Check the proxy settings of browser. Does it match the settings of your mail problem e.g.

Comment: idornt have proxsy because of it i have put no proxsy in ff proxsy setting.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking your DNS.  Open command prompt and try to ping google.com, if that doesn't work try pinging 72.14.213.104, which is a google.com IP.  If it doesn't work for the address, but it does for the IP, you probably have a DNS issue.

You could try to manually set your DNS to something new like 8.8.8.8 which is google's new DNS, or 4.2.2.2 (not google)